# How do we extract JSON data from Binance using Pandas in python, to get account equity?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binance-api-client

I am trying to calculate my account equity in BTC (I am just running the testnet at the moment) from Binance using the official python library. The response is a JSON format giving the name of the asset, the free and the locked balances. I can store this as a .txt file, or a csv.

[image: Screenshot of the resulting txt file]

I need to somehow extract the information, convert the balance for each coin to it's current equivalent in BTC, then add all of those up, giving me an overall account equity.

There is another endpoint which I can pull account snapshot from but that is only updated once a day and is not sufficient for what I am trying to do.

I have tried to learn how to use pandas in python and learn how to write functions. I ahve done neither before as my coding requirements have been relatively straightforward and I have not needed functions.
This is what I have written.

```
from binance.spot import Spot
import config
import sys
import importlib
import pandas as pd
import csv
import sys
import importlib
import requests
import time


Client = Spot(config.apiKey,config.apiSecret)


info = Client.account()
bal = info['balances']
for b in bal:
    if ((float(b['free']))>0) or ((float(b['free']))>0):
        original_stdout = sys.stdout
        file = open('balances.txt','a') 
        with file as f:
            sys.stdout = f
            print(b)
            file.close()
            sys.stdout = original_stdout


df = pd.read_csv('balances.txt',names=['Asset Full String', 'Free Balance', 'Locked Balance', 'BTC Pair', 'Xrate', 'Balance' ])
print(df)
def coinpair():
    cell = df.loc[:,'Asset Full String']
    strcell = cell.to_string(index = False, header=False)
    lenstr= len(strcell)
    coin = (strcell[11:lenstr-1])
    if coin != 'BTC':
       result = (strcell[11:lenstr-1])+'BTC'
       return result
    else:
       coin = 'BTC-nap' 
       return result         

df['BTC Pair']= df['Asset Full String'].apply(coinpair())
    

print(df)
```

The idea is that I will write a function for each column, then sum the final column. The above leads to[image: Powershell screenshot]

I understand that I have not written the other 2 functions yet, but I clearly don't understand how to process the data in 1 column and insert it into another.

I can get the exchange rate for a single pair, like this;

```
if coin != "BTC":
    coinpair = (strcell[11:lenstr-1])+"BTC"
    klines = Client.klines(coinpair,"1d", limit =1)
    closeLoc = {}
    for i in klines:
       close = closeLoc[i[0]] = i[1:2]
       strClose = str(close)
       length = len(strClose)
       string = strClose[2:length-2]
       num = float(string)
       print(num)
else:
    num = 1
    print(num)
```

but I want to be able to do that for all columns, where the row is not empty, then multipley that by the balance for another column, then sum the output.

Advice much appreciated

Comment: Are u able to create dataframe successfully ???

Comment: Yes. If I comment out and remove the function, I get a dataframe with Columns Asset Full String, Free Balance and Locked Balance, with Columns BTC Pair, Xrate and Balanec all registereing as NaN. I don't know how to return the expected values of the function coinpair(), to the 'BTC Pair' column. The Asset Full string reads "{ 'asset' : 'ETH'". I need to extract ETH, place BTC on the end, (so I get ETHBTC', then use that to get the correct kline close, and insert that into the next column. Then I need to multiple the free balances and locled balances, and sum them all, to get my equity.

Answer (score 0):

Client.account() [looks like](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#account-information-user_data):

```json
{
  "makerCommission": 15,
  "takerCommission": 15,
  "buyerCommission": 0,
  "sellerCommission": 0,
  "canTrade": true,
  "canWithdraw": true,
  "canDeposit": true,
  "brokered": false,
  "updateTime": 123456789,
  "accountType": "SPOT",
  "balances": [
    {
      "asset": "BTC",
      "free": "4723846.89208129",
      "locked": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
      "asset": "LTC",
      "free": "4763368.68006011",
      "locked": "0.00000000"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "SPOT"
  ]
}
```

Client.klines() [looks like](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#kline-candlestick-data):

```json
[
  [
    1499040000000,      // Kline open time
    "0.01634790",       // Open price
    "0.80000000",       // High price
    "0.01575800",       // Low price
    "0.01577100",       // Close price
    "148976.11427815",  // Volume
    1499644799999,      // Kline Close time
    "2434.19055334",    // Quote asset volume
    308,                // Number of trades
    "1756.87402397",    // Taker buy base asset volume
    "28.46694368",      // Taker buy quote asset volume
    "0"                 // Unused field, ignore.
  ]
]
```

There's no reason to ignore a perfectly good dictionary/list when it's given to you on a silver platter...

```py
from binance.spot import Spot
import config
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Client = Spot(config.apiKey,config.apiSecret)

info = Client.account()
bal = info['balances']

# Read your dictionary...
df = pd.DataFrame(bal)

# Convert to floats - if necessary:
df[['free', 'locked']] = df[['free', 'locked']].astype(float)

# Make your BTC Pair column.
df['BTC Pair'] = np.where(df.asset.eq('BTC'), 'BTC-nap', df.asset.add('-BTC'))

def klines(pair):
    lines = Client.klines(pair, '1d', limit=1)
    return float(lines[0][4])

df['kline'] = df['BTC Pair'].apply(klines)

print(df)
```

Output:

```py
  asset          free  locked BTC Pair     kline
0   BTC  4.723847e+06     0.0  BTC-nap  0.015771
1   LTC  4.763369e+06     0.0  LTC-BTC  0.015571
```

Comment: I get a completely different response. "Illegal characters foind in payameter 'symbol'. Ive continued to debug but I'm, getting nowehere. I don't understand how you ended up with your output. I copy pasted your code in its entirety.

Comment: I may have formatted the coinpair incorrectly, I don't know what format `Client.klines` is expecting.